# Compress all folders in a directory into their own .rar files

Tags: command-line, compression, rar

I have a directory with lots of sub directories inside of it and I want to find a way to turn all of those sub directories into their own .rar files using the terminal, since there are too many to do individually. I need each sub directory to be it's own .rar file as opposed to just raring the main directory into one big .rar file, because the sub directories have to go to different places once their compressed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need .rar extension then you need to install rar.

```
sudo apt install rar
```

The following commands will compress all the directories in current working directory (Use command `pwd` to know your current directory):

```
for dir in */
do
  base=$(basename "$dir")
  rar a "${base}" "$dir"
done
```

For normal tar balls you can use:

```
cd directory
for dir in */
do
  base=$(basename "$dir")
  tar -czf "${base}.tar.gz" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: That works perfectly except for the fact that some of my folders have spaces in their names, and it is skipping over those, I assume I need to add quotations somewhere in there but where?

Comment: Oh right! I should've put the quotations in the same place as the second one so it goes like this: rar a "${base}" "$dir"

Comment: I'm using the first one you recommended and it's recognizing the folders with spaces in their names, but it says "WARNING: No files" when attempting to rar any folder with a space in the name, the error however does not appear when raring folders without spaces in their names.

Comment: "WARNING: No files" means that the folder is empty and It won't be compressed. It shouldn't have anything to do with spaces.

Comment: The problem is that the folder is definitely not empty, I know there are other folders and files inside the folders that I'm getting the "WARNING: No files" error in. It seems that the directories that I'm getting this error on do not have files inside of them, but rather only folders in them which contain files.